# Como encontrar RegExp exato e fazer isso usando sintaxe construtora?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Eu tenho um algoritmo que pega vários caminhos completos de arquivos e verifica se cada um deles é 'proibido' pelo servidor.

O `var s` do `for` é referente a cada um desses caminhos e o `sets` é um array com expressões regulares a serem verificadas.

O problema é que, por exemplo, se eu tiver 4 arquivos nomeados de aq, aq2, aq3 e aq4 e definir no `array` que eu quero probidir apenas o aq e aq4, todos serão probidios... dai que o termo precisa ser exato.

Também não consegui usar Regex literal com valor de `sets[s]` então quero saber como fazer isso usando sintaxe construtora.

```
var sets = ['contatos/aq', 'contatos/aq4'];

for(var s=0; s < sets.length; s++) {
                var comst = 
               if( new RegExp(sets[s]).test(path_p) ) { // se arquivo for proibido pelo sets... 
                    if(testheader.test(read) && testfooter.test(read)){
                        read = read.replace(testheader, '');
                        read = read.replace(testfooter, '');
                        fs.writeFileSync(totxt, read);
                    }
                    fs.renameSync(totxt, path_p);
                    return false;
               }
           }
```

Comment: Impressão minha, ou seu código está incompleto? O que é esse `var comst = ` solto ali na 4° linha?

Comment: De uma olha [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/rbetsmkt/) mexi em algumas coisas e fiz alguns testes e aparentemente de forma simples está funcionando, verifique se lhe ajuda.

Comment: @Fernando eu cometei um pequeno erro: os arquivos são na verdade aq, aq2, aq3 e aq4. Já editei. Entendeu porque tem que ser um Regex exato agora?

Comment: Quando você diz exato você diz: `'contatos/aq' == 'contatos/aq'`?

Comment: @Fernando isso mesmo.

Comment: Então faça uma verificação simples, sem expressão regular, de uma olhada [nisso](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/rbetsmkt/1/). É assim?

Comment: @Fernando Acontece que os caminhos completos são mais ou menos isso: __dirname/pasta/subpasta/home/contatos/aq.ejs

Comment: Fiz da maneira como você comentou de uma olhada [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/rbetsmkt/2/), se for isso me avise que elaboro uma resposta explicando mais detalhadamente a solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme informações que você especificou nos comentários, o que você necessita é de uma solução aparentemente como está (Acompanhe os comentários no código):

```js
// SOLUÇÂO -----------------------------

// informe as extenções que serão ignoradas na comparação
var extensions_ignore = ['.ejs'];

// informe os arquivos que são negados/proibidos 
var proibidos = ['contatos/aq', 'contatos/aq1', 'contatos/aq4'];

// método de verificação se path é permitido 
var isPermitido = function(path_p){
    // faz um replace 
    path_p = replaceExtensionsIgnored(path_p);
    for(var s=0; s < proibidos.length; s++) {
        // verfica se o path termina com algum dos caminho proibidos
        if(path_p.endsWith(proibidos[s])) { 
            return false;
        }
    }
    // se passar por todos os caminho proibidos é por que está liberado, então retorna true
    return true;
};

// remove extensão ignora do caminho
var replaceExtensionsIgnored = function(path){
    for (var i = 0; i < extensions_ignore.length; i++){
        path = path.replace(extensions_ignore[i], "");
    }
    return path;
};

var test = function(path){    
    print(path + " : " + isPermitido(path));
};

var initTests = function(){
    // inicializa recursos (fallbacks)
    init();
    
    print("Iniciando Testes...")
    test('__dirname/pasta/subpasta/home/contatos/aq');
    test('__dirname/pasta/subpasta/home/contatos/aq2.ejs');
    test('__dirname/pasta/subpasta/home/contatos/aq3.ejs');
    test('__dirname/pasta/subpasta/home/contatos/aq4.ejs');
}

// -- Recursos extras -----

var init = function(){
      fallbacks();
}

// (Não relevante) metódo para printar resultado
var print = function(message){
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        // se for node.js
        console.log(message);
    }else{
        // se for DOM        
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.textContent = "  >  " + message;
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
};

var fallbacks = function(){
     /* Fallbsack para manter o support ao metodo em todas as versões do javascript já que este método está em versão experiemntal : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith */
    
    if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
      Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'endsWith', {
        value: function(searchString, position) {
          var subjectString = this.toString();
          if (position === undefined || position > subjectString.length) {
            position = subjectString.length;
          }
          position -= searchString.length;
          var lastIndex = subjectString.indexOf(searchString, position);
          return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
        }
      });
    }
};

// ------ init tests
initTests();
```

> Também postei uma versão paralela do código [aqui no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/rbetsmkt/6/)
>
> Sei que esse código não cobre todas os casos, mas é uma opção de caminho para a solução.

Conforme seu comentário testei aqui no node.js e único erro que ocorreu foi no método `print`, que não encontrava o document no node.js (já que não há), mas só lembrando que esse método é irrelevante para a solução, é só para printar os testes.

Alterei o método `print()` para verificar e printar no node.js e no DOM. Agora este mesmo código executa no node.js.

[Aqui tem um exemplo online](http://runnable.com/VLjuxHmqlCktck2a/test-node-js-for-hello-world) da solução em node.js

Comment: obrigado, cara. Mas no meu node não funcionou. De toda forma estou desistindo do que eu ia fazer.

Comment: Ok. Mas se não solucionou seu problema, não marque como resposta (eu fico feliz de você ter marcado, ganho pontos com isso, mas posso perde-los sem nenhum problema, se desejar aguardar uma resposta que resolva seu problema).

Comment: @ropbla9 Vamos tentar fazer funcionar no node.js. Qual erro está ocorrendo no node.js, para que essa solução não funcione?

Comment: @ropbla9 Verifiquei o que estava ocorrendo de errado no node.js, corrige e editei a resposta, acompanhe a edição da resposta.